# PostgreSQL Query not executing or takes too much time

Tags: performance, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 9.2 on windows while executing [***this***](http://pastebin.com/aRTwCThd) query:

```
SELECT
    gtab16.VrId,
    coalesce((
        select (gtab09.TdAmt+gtab09.CdAmt)
        from gtab09
        Where gtab09.JrmId = gtab16.JrmId
        limit 1
        ), 0::money
    ) as DisAmount,
    gtab02.VrName,
    gtab02.Vrlongname,
    gtab16.AcYrId,
    CASE WHEN gtab16.vrid = 28 THEN gtab16.RefNo ELSE gtab16.VrNo END AS VrNo,
    gtab16.RefNo,
    CASE
        WHEN gtab16.VrId = 10 THEN cast((
            Select coalesce(PBillDate,null)
            from gtab09
            Where gtab09.JrmId = gtab16.JrmId
        ) as bpchar)
        ELSE ''
    END As BillDate ,
    Cast(gtab16.VrDate As timestamp) As VrDate,
    gtab16.AgeDate,
    (
        SELECT coalesce(Sum(gtab18.ageamt),0::money)
        FROM
            (gtab16 AS A INNER JOIN gtab17 AS B ON A.jrmId = B.JrmId)
            INNER JOIN
            gtab18 ON B.JrDetId = gtab18.crjrdetid
        WHERE gtab18.drjrdetid = Gtab17.JrDetId AND A.AgeDate <= '2014-07-09'
    ) AS AgedAmt,
    case when gtab17.dr > 0::money then gtab17.Dr else gtab17.Cr end  AS VrAmt,
    gtab17.AcId, gtab12.AcName,
    gtab12.AcShortName,
    gtab12.PhoneOff,
    case when gtab17.cr > 0::money then 1 else 0 end AS Receipt,
    gtab47.AreaName,
    gtab16.JrMId,
    gtab17.JrDetId,
    date_part('day','2014-07-09' - Gtab16.agedate) as DayCount,
    (
        SELECT coalesce(sum(chqAmt),0::money)
        From gtab19
        Where PartyAcId = gtab17.acid and vrid = 19 And Pdc =1
    ) as PDCCheq,
    30 As Span1,
    60 As Span2,
    90 As Span3
FROM
    (
        gtab16
        INNER JOIN
        (
            gtab17
            INNER JOIN
            gtab12 ON gtab17.AcId = gtab12.acid
        ) ON gtab16.jrmId = gtab17.JrmId
    )
    INNER JOIN gtab02 ON gtab16.VrId = gtab02.vrId
    INNER JOIN gtab47 ON gtab12.AreaId = gtab47.AreaId
WHERE
    gtab16.BranchID = 1 And
    gtab17.Dr > 0::money AND
    case when gtab16.AcYrid = 2 then 1 else gtab16.VrId  end <> 6 And
    date_part('day','2014-07-09' - Gtab16.agedate)  >= 0 AND
    (gtab12.AcGrCode = '204' or gtab12.AcGrCode = '103') And
    gtab47.AreaId IN (7) AND
    date_part('day',  '2014-07-09' - gtab16.AgeDate) >= 0 And
    (gtab17.Dr - (
        SELECT coalesce(Sum(gtab18.ageamt),0::money)
        From
            (
                gtab16 AS A
                INNER JOIN gtab17 AS B ON A.jrmId = B.JrmId
            )
            INNER JOIN gtab18 ON B.JrDetId = gtab18.crjrdetid
        Where
            gtab18.drjrdetid = Gtab17.JrDetId AND
            A.AgeDate <= '2014-07-09') > 0::money
    ) AND
    gtab16.VrDate Between '2014-07-01' And '2014-07-09'
```

it takes long time, and [***here***](http://explain.depesz.com/s/ETx5) is the `explain analyze`:

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..98913858.59 rows=9 width=363) (actual time=302403.378..302628.382 rows=71 loops=1)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on gtab47  (cost=0.00..1.30 rows=1 width=122) (actual time=0.006..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Filter: (areaid = 7)"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 23"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..98908508.69 rows=9 width=249) (actual time=302400.148..302405.795 rows=71 loops=1)"
"        Join Filter: (gtab16.vrid = gtab02.vrid)"
"        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 3834"
"        ->  Seq Scan on gtab02  (cost=0.00..1.55 rows=55 width=150) (actual time=0.004..0.052 rows=55 loops=1)"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..98908499.74 rows=9 width=103) (actual time=5380.762..5498.218 rows=71 loops=55)"
"              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..98908499.70 rows=9 width=103) (actual time=295941.855..302398.524 rows=71 loops=1)"
"                    Join Filter: (gtab17.jrmid = gtab16.jrmid)"
"                    Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1886191"
"                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..98897543.98 rows=2015 width=69) (actual time=7.437..299102.826 rows=2037 loops=1)"
"                          Join Filter: (gtab17.acid = gtab12.acid)"
"                          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 12893055"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on gtab17  (cost=0.00..98819605.03 rows=29138 width=28) (actual time=2.974..276230.715 rows=68228 loops=1)"
"                                Filter: ((dr > (0)::money) AND ((dr - (SubPlan 5)) > (0)::money))"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 111761"
"                                SubPlan 5"
"                                  ->  Aggregate  (cost=548.98..549.00 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=3.131..3.132 rows=1 loops=88001)"
"                                        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..548.98 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2.707..3.126 rows=0 loops=88001)"
"                                              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..548.64 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=2.701..3.119 rows=0 loops=88001)"
"                                                    ->  Seq Scan on gtab18 gtab18_1  (cost=0.00..540.19 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=2.693..3.109 rows=0 loops=88001)"
"                                                          Filter: (drjrdetid = gtab17.jrdetid)"
"                                                          Rows Removed by Filter: 28575"
"                                                    ->  Index Scan using gtab17_pkey on gtab17 b_1  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=28574)"
"                                                          Index Cond: (jrdetid = gtab18_1.crjrdetid)"
"                                              ->  Index Scan using gtab16_pkey on gtab16 a_1  (cost=0.29..0.33 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=28574)"
"                                                    Index Cond: (jrmid = b_1.jrmid)"
"                                                    Filter: (agedate <= '2014-07-09 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)"
"                          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..140.94 rows=178 width=45) (actual time=0.001..0.160 rows=189 loops=68228)"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on gtab12  (cost=0.00..140.05 rows=178 width=45) (actual time=0.057..0.927 rows=189 loops=1)"
"                                      Filter: ((areaid = 7) AND (((acgrcode)::text = '204'::text) OR ((acgrcode)::text = '103'::text)))"
"                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 2385"
"                    ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..3037.42 rows=262 width=38) (actual time=0.006..0.788 rows=926 loops=2037)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on gtab16  (cost=0.00..3036.11 rows=262 width=38) (actual time=10.342..13.037 rows=926 loops=1)"
"                                Filter: ((vrdate >= '2014-07-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (vrdate <= '2014-07-09 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (branchid = 1) AND (CASE WHEN (acyrid = 2) THEN 1 ELSE vrid END <> 6) AND (date_p (...)"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 58837"
"  SubPlan 1"
"    ->  Limit  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=1 loops=71)"
"          ->  Index Scan using gtab09_jrmid_idx on gtab09  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=71)"
"                Index Cond: (jrmid = gtab16.jrmid)"
"  SubPlan 2"
"    ->  Index Scan using gtab09_jrmid_idx on gtab09 gtab09_1  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=8) (never executed)"
"          Index Cond: (jrmid = gtab16.jrmid)"
"  SubPlan 3"
"    ->  Aggregate  (cost=548.98..549.00 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2.975..2.975 rows=1 loops=71)"
"          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.71..548.98 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=2.968..2.970 rows=0 loops=71)"
"                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..548.64 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=2.965..2.966 rows=0 loops=71)"
"                      ->  Seq Scan on gtab18  (cost=0.00..540.19 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=2.959..2.960 rows=0 loops=71)"
"                            Filter: (drjrdetid = gtab17.jrdetid)"
"                            Rows Removed by Filter: 28575"
"                      ->  Index Scan using gtab17_pkey on gtab17 b  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                            Index Cond: (jrdetid = gtab18.crjrdetid)"
"                ->  Index Scan using gtab16_pkey on gtab16 a  (cost=0.29..0.33 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                      Index Cond: (jrmid = b.jrmid)"
"                      Filter: (agedate <= '2014-07-09 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)"
"  SubPlan 4"
"    ->  Aggregate  (cost=28.63..28.64 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.130..0.131 rows=1 loops=71)"
"          ->  Seq Scan on gtab19  (cost=0.00..28.62 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.124..0.124 rows=0 loops=71)"
"                Filter: ((partyacid = gtab17.acid) AND (vrid = 19) AND (pdc = 1))"
"                Rows Removed by Filter: 607"
"Total runtime: 302628.704 ms"
```

- `PostgreSQL` server side `config`

> max_connections   10000
>   max_stack_depth   2MB
>   shared_buffers    1GB
>   temp_buffers  1GB

am new so any suggestions or advices are much appreciated

Comment: The query is pretty illegible. Thanks very much for including it and `explain analyze` though. It looks like your rowcount estimates are fine. 90% of the time is spent in the seqscan on node 19.

Comment: @CraigRinger  as i said am new what should i do next ??

Comment: What's the storage on this system? For testing purposes *only* try re-trunning the query with `SET random_page_cost = 1.1`. Also try `SET enable_nestloop = off` and show the resulting plans.

Comment: @CraigRinger So how can i fix it ??

Comment: Please re-read my previous comment. Run those tests. Edit the question to add the results. That might provide enough info; right now it's hard to be sure. Please also show output of `\d gtab18` and `\d gtab17` and `\d gtab16`. (If those are "anonymized" table names, you get to figure out which ones they are in your real data).

Comment: i have executed `SET random_page_cost = 1.1` and `SET enable_nestloop = off` before executing my `query` but still the same or am i doing anything wrong ?? and `output of \d gtab18 and \d gtab17 and \d gtab16` means ???

Comment: As for `\d` ... I guess you must be using PgAdmin not `psql` then, so you wouldn't know what `\d` is; don't worry about that. What I'm asking for is a listing of the indexes defined on the tables you have called `gtab18`, `gtab17` and `gtab16`. I suspect you have "anonymized" this query plan, in which case you have to figure out what the corresponding *real* table names are and show the indexes on them.

Comment: and re `SET enable_nestloop = off` ... I don't believe that didn't change anything, unless you did it in a different session where it had no effect. It should've changed the plan or *at least* the cost parameters. How are you running this query? How did you run `SET enable_nestloop = off`?

Comment: @CraigRinger just see [this](http://s18.postimg.org/81mx76iih/ind.jpg)

Comment: Possible an index on `gtab17.jrdetid` may help, but really I think I'd have to format that query into something vaguely legible then analyse this properly. No time for that for a giant wall-of-unformatted-text query. I suspect a few composite indexes are really going to be called for. I'm going to have to leave it at that and let someone else pick up helping you, sorry.

Comment: Off-topic: `... Select coalesce(PBillDate,null) from ...` is the result of madness, IMHO.

Comment: All those scalar sub-queries in the `select` list (using `limit 1`) look somewhat fishy to me. If they are really needed this _could_ indicate a problem in the data model.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how to simplfy this select ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on http://explain.depesz.com/, you will see where your query was slow.

but before doing query optimisation , read a tutorial about it to understand what is seqscan/loop/cast etc... and please try to rewrite your query to do it more simple! i think you can.

Read what @wildplasser said because `Select coalesce(PBillDate,null) from` is due to an incomprehensive use of coalesce...`Select PBillDate from`  is the same so don't do not necessary treatment.

But to help you, when I'm in this case, I try to remove all the select clause to kept only one and remove join that are not necessary for my select clause and play the query. try to re-add select clause one by one with the correct join and if you see your query time growing, do an explain, go to depesz website to read the explain and try to detect where your query was slow and add index or rewrite it.

It's very hard to read a big query and try to optimize it, so add select clause step by step and you will find your solution.

and check if your statistics are ok, if not your explain will be not correct. you can do vacuum to refresh your stat. And try `explain analyze` instead of `explain` because `explain analyze` played the real query and return you many other information to see the cost of each part.

Read a tutorial on explain analyze because you have many options very useful ;)

Best regards

Comment: anyways thanks for the _infos_ i have figured out the problem that the main reason was 3 tables in that _query_ does not have _indexes_ finally i found it and assigned correct _index_ for them now my _query_ works well and again i need to _optimze_ it according to your _answer_